# How to: array_push into multiple array with a strict hierarchy?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build an archive-class for my firebird database. And I have the following problem a couple of times already:

**I want to construct an array-structure like that:**

```
/**
 *  @var [] stores the success log of all db operations
 *
 *  $_log = Array(
 *      (string) [DATA_SOURCE] => Array(
 *          (int) [0] => Array(
 *              (string) [id]       => (int) 32,
 *              (string) [action]   => (string) "update/insert/delete",
 *              (string) [state]    => (int) 1,
 *              (string) [message]  => (string) "success/error",
 *          )
 *      )
 *  )
 */
private $_log = array();
```

**MY 1. TRY:**

```
// push result to log array
array_push(
    $this->_log,
    array(
        "archive"   => array(
            "id"        => $row["ID"],
            "action"    => "update",
            "state"     => $success,
        ),
    )
);
```

**RESULTS IN:**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [archive] => Array(
            [id] => 32
            [action] => update
            [state] => 1
        )

    )
)
```

That's not exactly what i want. I want the "data-source"-key here "archive" in front of the pushed entry [0].

**MY 2nd TRY**

```
array_push(
    $this->_log["archive"],
    array(
        "id"        => $row["ID"],
        "action"    => "update",
        "state"     => $success,
    )
);
```

**RESULTS IN**

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>/Users/rsteinmann/web/intranet/pages/firebird/ArchiveTables.php</b> on line <b>238</b><br />
```

I'm a bit helpless with this task. I also tried to find anything on google or stackoverflow but there was nothing really useful.

I would be so glad if someone could help me with that!

Thank you,
Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->log['archive'][] = array('id' => ...);
```

This is the sanest way to do it. PHP will create any non-existing keys (like `archive`) for you. `array_push` on the other hand is a function call and requires its arguments to already exist, it can't create a non-existing `archive` key for you. You'd have to do that before you call the function.

`array_push` is mostly useful if you need to push several arguments at once (`array_push($arr, $a, $b, $c)`), otherwise `$arr[] = $a` is the generally preferred and [officially recommended](http://php.net/array_push) syntax.

Comment: Now I feel sort of stupid :-D But yea this was the exact solution! Thank you so much, also for the explanation! For some reason i did not know that one can use empty key-brackets [].